# Spivak's Calculus chapter 11 problem 32 clarification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two differentiable functions which satisfy $fg'-f'g=0$. Prove that if $a$ and $b$ are adjacent zeros of $f$, and $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ are not both $0$, then $g(x)=0$ for some $x$ between $a$ and $b$. (Naturally the same result holds with $f$ and $g$ interchanged; thus, the zeros of $f$ and $g$ separate each other.) Hint: Derive a contradiction from the assumption that $g(x)\neq 0$ for all $x$ between $a$ and $b$: if a number is not $0$, there is a natural thing to do with it.

My proof:

Suppose $g(x) \neq 0$ for $x \in (a, b)$

This implies $\frac{f}{g}$ is differentiable on $(a, b)$

$$\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)' = \frac{f'g - fg'}{g^2}=0$$
This implies
$$f(x)=Cg(x)$$ where $C \neq0$ ($C = 0$ would make $a$ and $b$ not adjacent zeros of $f$)

Taking limits:
$$f(a)=\lim_{x \to a^+ }f(x)=\lim_{x \to a^+}Cg(x) = Cg(a)$$
$$Cg(a) = f(a) = 0 \Longrightarrow g(a) = 0$$

$$f(b)=\lim_{x \to b^- }f(x)=\lim_{x \to b^-}Cg(x) = Cg(b)$$
$$Cg(b) = f(b) = 0 \Longrightarrow g(b) = 0$$

This contradicts $g(a)$ and $g(b)$ both not $0$.

However by considering the derivative of $\frac{g}{f}$ on $(a,b)$

$$\left(\frac{g}{f}\right)' = \frac{fg'-f'g}{f^2} = 0$$
Which implies
$$g(x) = kf(x)$$
for some real number $k$

By taking limits we get $g(a) = kf(a) = 0$ and $g(b) = kf(b) = 0$ as before which leads to a contradiction.

I'm confused as to why the contradiction appears in the 2nd case even though i don't think it uses the assumption that $g(x) \neq 0$ on $(a, b)$. Did i use this assumption implicitly somewhere?

Comment: The first part of your proof already shows that the assumption $g(x) \ne 0$ on $(a, b)$ leads to a contradiction. Then you are done, the second part is not needed.

Comment: @MartinR I'm aware that the first part is sufficient i was just confused since i didn't need the assumption of $g(x) \neq 0$ and still got the contradiction

Comment: In the second case, the correct assumption would not be $f \neq 0$?

Comment: @Bruno that follows from $a$ and $b$ being adjacent zeros of $f$